# cx_Freeze is not finding self defined modules in my project when creating exe

Tags: python, module, exe, importerror, cx-freeze

I have a project that runs from GUI.py and imports modules I created. Specifically it imports modules from a "Library" package that exists in the same directory as GUI.py. I want to freeze the scripts with cx_Freeze to create a windows executable, and I can create the exe, but when I try to run it, I get: "ImportError: No module named Library."

I see in the output that all the modules that I import from Library aren't imported. Here's what my setup.py looks like:

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages":['Libary', 'Graphs', 'os'], 
                 "includes":["tkinter", "csv", "subprocess", "datetime", "shutil", "random", "Library", "Graphs"],
         "include_files": ['GUI','HTML','Users','Tests','E.icns', 'Graphs'],
        }

base = None
exe = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
exe = Executable(
    script="GUI.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = "Win32GUI",
    targetDir = r"built",
    targetName = "GUI.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = False,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = None
)
base = "Win32GUI"

setup( name = "MrProj",
version = "2.0",
description = "My project",
options = {"build.exe": build_exe_options},
#executables = [Executable("GUI.py", base=base)]
executables = [exe]
)
```

I've tried everything that I could find in StackOverflow and made a lot of fixes based upon similar problems people were having. However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get cx_freeze to import my modules in Library.

My setup.py is in the same directory as GUI.py and the Library directory.

I'm running it on a Windows 7 Laptop with cx_Freeze-4.3.3.

I have python 3.4 installed.

Any help would be a godsend, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the freeze output? Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but shouldn't `options = {"build.exe": build_exe_options}` be `options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}`?

Answer (score 0):

If `Library` (funny name by the way) in `packages` doesn't work you could try as a workaround to put it in the `includes` list. For this to work you maybe have to explicitly include every single submodule like:

```
includes = ['Library', 'Library.submodule1', 'Library.sub2', ...]
```

For the `include_files` you have to add each file with full (relative) path. Directories don't work.

You could of course make use of `os.listdir()` or the `glob` module to append paths to your include_files like this:

```
from glob import glob
...
include_files = ['GUI.py','HTML','Users','E.icns', 'Graphs'],
include_files += glob('Tests/*/*')
...
```

In some cases something like `sys.path.insert(0, '.')` or even `sys.path.insert(0, '..')` can help.